# Web Project not automatically creating virtual folder in IIS7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

We've got a rather strange problem, we have been debugging the last couple of days, without any result. We just reinstalled a new developer machine for a new colleauge and run into some problems the project type "Web Project" (has project type GUID E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A), which doesn't not create a virtual directory in the IIS7.5 on the newly installed machine. It works fine on all the other machines, but for some reason, this feature is not triggered when opening the solution.

Further information:

[image]

- The same code base
- Should be the same tool chain and versions
- On the machines that work, the project is named "http://localhost/DCFService"
- On the machine that doesn't work, the project is named the absolut path "C:\...\.."  (see attached
- The configuration in the solution file is of course identical on all machines and detail what virtual folder should be created and where:

  Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "DCFServices", "http://localhost/DCFServices", "{66A169D0-310D-45EC-927F-08E06C8885ED}"

Comment: Follow up information. The machines that are configured correctly, use the IIS as the default webserver (when debugging from vs), while the other machine uses the Cassini web server. How and where is the default web server specified?

Comment: Based on the information provided and the solution given, this sounds like a temporal bug/corruption in your user/project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not confirmed, but for future readers, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the user settings file (.suo).

My colleague deleted the workspace, delete the files, got a new snapshot from TFS - and Presto, the solution created the virtual directory in the IIS7.

So the solution might simply be deleting the suo file or deleting the workspace.